# Pound sign (£) rendered as <ffffffff> in zsh

Tags: keyboard, terminal, zsh, input, oh-my-zsh

Things I've ruled out

- **Terminal**: works if I launch it with `bash` as shell
- **Keyboard layout**: £ inserts fine in Vim, `bash` and Firefox
- **Unicode issues anywhere**: emojis work in all applications

I can't input £ in `zsh`, even when I launch `bash`, which probably means the ZSH Line Editor is at fault. But I can't find out
how to make it work by using `bindkey`, even after some Google searching.

Can I use `bindkey`, or do I have to use something else?

EDIT:

Locale Variables (same in `bash` and `zsh`):

Also using `oh-my-zsh` with default theme

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Terminal: `st` ([Luke Smith's build](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/st))

Comment: So it works if your terminal starts bash, but not if your terminal starts zsh and from that zsh you start bash? Sounds really weird. zsh's line editor should be irrelevant. You should start comparing bash's environment variables in these two cases, especially the locale-related ones.

Comment: This has pretty sure something with your locales to do. Is the locale en_GB.UTF-8 generated? Check with the command `locale -a`.

Comment: @mpy C, en_GB.utf8, POSIX

Comment: Okay, just to make sure: Have you tried with `zsh -f` (dont load d'oh-my-zsh) and then set `LC_ALL=en_GB.utf8`?

Comment: @mpy That doesn't change anything, but I realized running an `st` supbrocess form `st` solves the problem. It''s hacky though

Comment: It's stopped somehow??

Comment: I've got a similar issue. To me, it is rendered as `<ffffffff><ffffffff>`, black on white, as if it is selected. When selected becomes white on black, as if unselected. launching `bash` with `zsh` works, but it is reported as `$'\302\243'` by `stderr`. In `zsh`'s `stderr` it is `??` instead. Should I open a new question?

Comment: Hey @JeffreyLebowski, have you gone through `zkbd`? If not, and if you have any more problems, open a StackExchnage chat and I'll help

Comment: I have the same issue as @JeffreyLebowski (`<ffffffff><ffffffff>` in reverse video), even when removing my ~/.zshrc. I can type characters fine in `bash` or even if I run `read foo` from within `zsh`. I'm using `zsh` 5.7.1 packaged by nixpkgs (which does funky stuff with paths and env vars) on `xfce4-terminal` using a wayland compositor (`wayfire`).  `locale` gives sensible results (`en_GB.UTF-8` everywhere except `LANGUAGE=en_GB:en`, and `locale -a` does list `en_GB.UTF-8`).